# Enforcing correct state transitions at compile time

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I'm working on some code that creates packets of data in a specific format from some incoming data, which also includes a timestamp (which should be the time the first bit of data going into the packet was generated). At a (simplified) high level, this looks something like:

```
template <typename T>
class packetizer
{
public:
    set_payload(const T* data, uint16_t length, uint32_t timestamp);
};
```

There is an additional requirement to be able to add data piecemeal; something like:

```
uint16_t initial_data(const T* data, uint16_t length, uint32_t timestamp);
uint16_t append_data(const T* data, uint16_t length);
```

Here, the timestamp should be added only once, in the `initial_data` call. This all works, and can be checked at runtime, but so far I've been striving to provide an API that is as compile-time safe as possible - I'd like to enforce the above invariants at compile time. One way I've thought about doing this is returning a proxy:

```
struct proxy_packetizer
{
private:
    packetizer<T>& packet_ref;

public:
    uint16_t append_data(const T* data, uint16_t length)
    {
        // forward call to packet_ref
    }
};

template <typename T>
class packetizer
{
public:
    proxy_packetizer initial_data(const T* data, uint16_t length, uint32_t timestamp);
};
```

The use of which would look something like:

```
packetizer p;
auto p2 = p.initial_data(data, length, timestamp);
p2.append_data(....);
auto pkt = p2.create_packet(...);
```

However, this is a bit clunky, and still error-prone. I'd prefer instead if I could somehow have an API that looked more like:

```
packetizer p;
p.initial_data(data, length, timestamp);
p.append_data(...);
auto pkt = p.create_packet();
```

where it was enforced at compile time that:

1. `initial_data` is called once and only once for each packet.
2. `append_data` can be called only after `initial_data` is called.
3. `create_packet` resets this (so `initial_data` must once again be called).

Is there any compile-time way to enforce these kinds of state transitions?

Comment: Have you considered a more [RAII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) approach? Specifically: the constructor takes `(data, length, timestamp)` ensuring there's some data and exactly one timestamp, after which `append_data` can be called 0 or more times, then have a `reset(data, length, timestamp)` member akin to your `create_packet` (*if* there are resources worth reusing, otherwise just have the user create another object).

Comment: @TonyD Yes, there are definitely resources worth reusing, to save having to free/reallocate storage each time the user wants to create a packet. The constructor approach is a possibility (and a better one than what I have above), but doesn't *quite* eliminate API misuse (calling the constructor with arguments and then calling `set_payload`, for example).

Comment: I didn't suggest having a `set_payload`, but the arguments make it equivalent to the `reset()` function I suggested.  Why would that be a misuse?  Are you trying to compile-time enforce some other action in between - like say `send()`?

Comment: @TonyD No, the network layer is a separate issue that a higher level can deal with. My example would be a misuse as `set_payload` (or `reset`) presumes the data coming in is in a single chunk, and will simply overwrite the existing data given in the constructor.

Comment: *"presumes the data coming in is in a single chunk"* - not at all - just like the constructor, it could be followed by any number of appends.  *"will simply overwrite the existing data given in the constructor"* - it should overwrite that data and any other data appended beforehand, unless some other action like `send()` proactively clears out the already sent data.  And why is that undesirable?  Whether you call it `create_packet()` or `reset(data, length, timestamp)` or `set_payload(...)` - don't you want to clear out the old data and reuse the object resources?

Answer (score 1):

I would agree with the comment from @TonyD about having an RAII approach. The idea is to covert `packetizer::initial_data(...)` into a constructor `packetizer::packetizer(...)`. This is how, the `timestamp` will be set only once:

```
template <typename T>
class packetizer
{
public:
  packetizer(const T* data, uint16_t length, uint32_t timestamp);

  uint16_t append_data(const T* data, uint16_t length);
};
```

Since the initial data may come at anytime during runtime, you may use `operator new` for the same:

```
std::unique_ptr<packetizer<T>> packetizer = new Packetizer<T>(data, length, timestamp);
...
packetizer->append_data(data, length);
```

From whatever is mentioned in the question, I can't say much about `set_payload()`; but if it is error prone, then we should better eliminate it by changing the design.

Comment: Actually, thinking about it a bit more, this approach also has some problems, as it removes the ability for default construction. The user may want to use this as e.g. a class member, but the data may not be available until well after it has been instantiated.

Comment: @Yuushi, that's correct. For that purpose we have to use `operator new`, so that you can create an object only when the data is available. The other approach would be to use `std::vector` and `push_back` when the data is available. To ensure compile time enforcement, this limitation has to be dealt with. Otherwise, the way you described in your question is also helpful which doesn't require using `operator new`.

Answer (score 0):

After running into an implementation of an [IMAP State Machine](http://insanitybit.github.io/2016/05/30/beyond-memory-safety-with-types) in Rust that is verified at compile time, it seems like what I was looking for comes under the heading of a [Substructural Type System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substructural_type_system), in this case, probably an affine type system.

I haven't tried implementing it, but potentially this could be done with move-only types.